# AttributeError: 'AttributeValueAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have designed a table for attribute and product attributes. An attribute can have many values.
For example, an attribute called color can have values like Black, white, Grey, Maroon etc. For
this I designed a table such way

However when registering to the admin, I get `AttributeError: 'AttributeValueAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'`  error.

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Attribute"
        verbose_name_plural = "Attributes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductAttribute(SortableModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                                related_name="productattribute",
                                null=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ManyToManyField(
        Attribute,
        through="AttributeValue"
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("sort_order",)
        verbose_name = "Product Attribute"
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Attributes"



class AttributeValue(SortableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    productattribute = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute,
                                         null=True,
                                         related_name='productattribute',
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, related_name="values", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("sort_order", "id")
        unique_together = ("slug", "attribute")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.Product
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }


class AttributeValueAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.AttributeValue
    extra = 2


class AttributeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.Attribute
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }


class ProductAttributeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # model = models.ProductAttribute
    inlines = (AttributeValueAdmin, )


admin.site.register(models.Attribute, AttributeAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.AttributeValue, AttributeValueAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.ProductAttribute, ProductAttributeAdmin)
```

Comment: Maybe have to re-run migrations?

Comment: nup it gives me the same issues.

Comment: @milan Plz add your urls.py file of app as well as project

Comment: I am using graphql. There is only one end point i.e /graphql

Answer (score 1):

As per django docs on admin, the first step is to display the intermediate model by subclassing inline class for `AttributeValue` table like you have done

```
class AttributeValueInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.AttributeValue
    extra = 2
```

Second step is to create admin views for both `Attribute` and `ProductAttribute` models.

```
class AttributeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AttributeValueInline, )
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }


class ProductAttributeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AttributeValueInline, )
```

Third step is to register your `Attribute` and `ProductAttribute` models

```
admin.site.register(models.Attribute, AttributeAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.ProductAttribute, ProductAttributeAdmin)
```

You don't need to register `AttributeValue` model as you can create/edit `AttributeValue` inline from either `Attribute` or `ProductAttribute` table.

For reference you can read the django docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models